# Display all content in active cell with double click

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to display the all content in active cell via message box or userform using by double click on active cell.. Is it possible via VBA ? It has to be working dynamically according to the cell because every cell contains different sentences. The reason is the sentences are too long and it is hard to open every time due to format or visual quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in the Sheet module:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox Target, , "Cell contents"

    Cancel = True

End Sub
```

---

To show more than 1024 characters

- Create a new UserForm (`UserForm1` example in image bellow)

  - On the form create a new TextBox (`TextBox1`)
  - Set `TextBox1.MultiLine = True`, and `TextBox1.ScrollBars = 3 - FmScrollBarsBoth`

and use this in the Sheet module:

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    With UserForm1
        .Caption = "Cell contents"
        .TextBox1.Value = Target.Value
        .Show
    End With

    Cancel = True

End Sub
```

---

UserForm1

[image: UserForm1]

Comment: that works appreciate.. Is there anyway to adjust the format for the msgbox ? I would like to increase the size if possible

Comment: I did it as you clarified but userform did not work.. How can I trigger it? the content that I would like to display is columnD.

Comment: Make sure the UserForm Name is `UserForm1`, and TextBox Name is `TextBox1`, then place the second code in the Sheet's module (delete the other code)

Comment: Do you want to restrict the double-click to column D only?

Comment: I checked that and Userform name is userform1 and textbox name is Textbox1.. I mean the content that I would like to display is D column.. Every row has a different content and I would like to display one by one when I make a double click on that content. I deleted the other code as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169366/discussion-between-gamze-ural-and-paul-bica).